# Can't type anything when editing a Winform TreeNode

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently working on a level editor and for the list of levels and sublevels I wanted to use a `TreeView` control and of course add the option to easily rename them. So I set `LabelEdit` to `true` and when clicking on a `TreeNode` it does go into editing mode, but after that I can't actually type anything. I can exit editing with enter or escape, select parts, but I can't delete, add or change something.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here and it's not easy to find any information related to my problem.

Here's the code:

```
void SetupWindow()
{
    // It's part of a XNA project, so the handle comes
    // from the XNA generated window.
    form = Control.FromHandle(this.Window.Handle) as Form;

    Panel panel = new Panel();
    panel.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
    panel.Width = 224;

    // [...menu stuff...]

    screenList = new TreeView();
    screenList.Width = 212;
    screenList.Height = 150;
    screenList.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 348);
    screenList.LabelEdit = true;

    panel.Controls.Add(screenList);
    form.Controls.Add(panel);

    AddScreen();
}

void AddScreen()
{
    screenList.Nodes.Add(screenCount.ToString(), "Screen " + screenCount);
    screenCount++;
}
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is something else in the process eating queued messages?

Comment: To ensure this is a TreeView issue try to add a TextBox instead and edit in there.

Comment: Ok, since the only other thing going on in the project so far is the XNA main loop, I bypassed that code and ran the form in it's own window, which solved the typing problem. So it seems that sharing the window XNA opens up messes with my ability to type in text. I just checked and it doesn't work with TextBoxes either, so it seems XNA is somehow intercepting my keyboard input, which is strange because the shortcuts I defined for my menus work just fine.

Comment: Just googled this: http://romsteady.blogspot.com/2011/06/key-events-in-xna-40.html

Comment: Yes, it seems I'll have to find a workaround. Still weird that some input is received and some is not (enter, escape and the shortcuts are working). Right now I'm looking into keeping my GUI in a seperate window, that just seems a bit easier to me.